# Automação de GUI com python

Tags: python, gui

Seguinte, estou querendo começar um projeto de criar um bot para um jogo especifico de android em python, para isso, utilizo de um emulador, o nox. A minha ideia é conseguir trabalhar com a parte de automação de gui(clicks automáticos, apertar um botão do teclado, etc) de uma forma em background, no caso, que pudesse deixar a janela minimizada, e ir realizando outras tarefas.

A biblioteca que encontrei par ao python de automação de gui foi a PyAutoGUI, porém você só consegue realizar os clicks na janela inteira, se os pixels aparecerem atualmente na tela, o que não vai ocorrer caso o processo esteja minimizado

Existe alguma forma da qual eu consigo fazer esse processo com a janela minimizada?

Segue exemplo de um código bem simples para dar uma exemplificada

```
import os
import pygetwindow
import time
import pyautogui

title = "NoxPlayer"

os.startfile(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Nox\bin\nox.exe")

time.sleep(5)

window = pygetwindow.getWindowsWithTitle(title)[0]
window.activate()
window.resizeTo(1280,720)
window.moveTo(0,0)

time.sleep(5)

posx, posy, height, wight = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(r"Images\Icon.png")
pyautogui.moveTo(posx + 10, posy + 10, 1)
```

Comment: pode apresentar um exemplo mínimo replicável?

Comment: editei a pergunta com um exemplo

Comment: não acho que va conseguir, pyautogui automatiza a interface, se a janela esta minimizada não vai ter interface grafica para ser automatizada, talvez funcione em uma maquinavirtual, o script rodando dentro dela junto do aplicativo, ai talvez vc posso minimizar a janela da maquinavirtual

Answer (score 1):

> Existe alguma forma da qual eu consigo fazer esse processo com a
>   janela minimizada?

Não. Será necessário maximizar a janela para que os métodos de busca de imagem (como o 'locateonscreen') possam ser utilizados.

Para maximizar uma janela, costumo utilizar a função abaixo.
O argumento 'win_name' deve ser o nome do processo/janela que se pretende maximizar.

```
def win_act(win_name):
    import win32gui
    import re

    class WindowMgr:
        """Encapsulates some calls to the winapi for window management"""

        def __init__(self):
            """Constructor"""
            self._handle = None

        def find_window(self, class_name, window_name=None):
            """find a window by its class_name"""
            self._handle = win32gui.FindWindow(class_name, window_name)

        def _window_enum_callback(self, hwnd, wildcard):
            """Pass to win32gui.EnumWindows() to check all the opened windows"""
            if re.match(wildcard,
                         str(win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd))) is not None:
                self._handle = hwnd

        def find_window_wildcard(self, wildcard):
            """find a window whose title matches the wildcard regex"""
            self._handle = None
            win32gui.EnumWindows(self._window_enum_callback, wildcard)

        def set_foreground(self):
            """put the window in the foreground"""
            win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(self._handle)

    w = WindowMgr()
    for x in range(3):
        w.find_window_wildcard(f".*{win_name}*")
        # time.sleep(2)
        w.set_foreground()
```